# How to set up 4.4 android SystemUI - statusbar is transparent

Tags: android

I want to achieve the thought is this

[image]

but the actual effect is like this

[image]

---

I set status_bar  background is `"#00000000"`
and `mStatusBarView.findViewById(R.id.status_bar).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.transparents_img);`

~~~

The background is still black

```
<com.android.systemui.statusbar.phone.PhoneStatusBarView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:systemui="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.android.systemui"
    android:id="@+id/status_bar"
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" >
```

---

```
<com.android.systemui.statusbar.phone.StatusBarWindowView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:systemui="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.android.systemui"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="#00000000"
    style="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" >
```

what else needs to be changed in order to be transparent